# Page Navigation Issues ionic2 and angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 app, there are two pages but after `ProfilePage` gets loaded, it pushes the `LoginPage`, and then it refreshes it and the page becomes blank. Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is my code

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
 })
 export class AuthApp {
   rootPage: any = ProfilePage;

   constructor(platform: Platform, private auth: AuthService) {
     platform.ready().then(() => {       
       StatusBar.styleDefault();
       auth.startupTokenRefresh();
     });
   }
 }
```

profile.ts

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth/auth.service';
 import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

 @Component({
   templateUrl: 'profile.html',
 })
 export class ProfilePage {
   constructor(public auth: AuthService, public navCtrl: NavController) {

   }

   ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.auth.authenticated())
    if (!this.auth.authenticated()) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    }
   }
 }
```

login.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
 @Component({
   templateUrl: 'login.html',
 })
 export class LoginPage {
    authType: string = "login";
    error: string;

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
 }
```

Is there any suggestion about what I am doing wrong? Why does the `LoginPage` gets refreshed when it is pushed?

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: nothing in the console

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are setting the page as root instead of pushing it. Instead of `this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);` you can try `this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);`

Answer (score 0):

Does the console.log statement in `ngOnInit()` get printed twice?

`ngOnInit()` might be called **twice**: Once when you declare the page, and a second time whenever you pushed the page.

You can try and change `ngOnInit()` to `ionViewDidLoad()` (see [this resource](http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/) for more)

In any case, it would much help if you could post the contents of the `app.module.ts` file. Why is there no `@IonicPage` decorator in your page classes?